# Dependent dropdown in yii

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

In my page I have two dropdown lists, both of them multiselect dropdowns. And second one depends first dropdown. For example,

1-dropdown is fruits, vegetables, drinks;

2-dropdown depends user selection, if user select fruit and drinks, it should be display apple, grapes, juice, bier ( all together in one dropdownlist );

If user select only one option e.g vegetables in first dropdown, second should display onion, potato etc.

Please give suggeestion, I want to do this in Yii Framework. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must include the attempt you have made so far to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Here is my code please check and help me to solve this issue.

Comment: where is the code? you should update your question including it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wiki entry from Yii detailing exactly how to do this.

[Create a dependent dropdown](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/creating-a-dependent-dropdown/)